# Can't update data in sql

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me what is the problem with query bellow

Code :-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require('../../conn/include.php');

$sel="SELECT * from `activites` where act_id='".$_REQUEST['doo']."'";
$query=mysql_query($sel);
$reader=mysql_fetch_array($query);


$title=$_POST['tit'];
$descrip=$_POST['description'];
$project=$_POST['project'];
$visibality=$_POST['vasiblity'];

if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
{

$updat="UPDATE `my`.`activites` SET `title`='$title',`description`='$descrip',`project`='$project',`published` ='$visibality' WHERE `activites`.`act_id` ='".$_REQUEST['doo']."'";

    $que=mysql_query($updat);
    header('Location:acti.php');
    exit(); 
}
```

Comment: Undfined index in line 5 and line 11

Comment: So.. could you point out lines 5 and 11 of the file or include them above?

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST);` make sure you got the  `update` and `upd` values?

Comment: What is the error that the MySQL server gives? Also, for security, you should sanitize the database inputs using a function like mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: i get everything from array
  'doo' => string '22' (length=2)

Comment: when i submit the form i get
Undefined index: doo in line 5

Answer (score 2):

Is this suppose to be $_REQUEST['update']?

```
where act_id='".$_REQUEST['upd']."'";
```

Comment: thank you but its ok update is the name of submit button

Comment: Try removing the single quotes so it's                             WHERE act_id=".$_REQUEST['doo']."";